# Can I use a 0 mm top layer thickness in Ultimaker Cura to create an open box?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Let's say I'm modeling a simple open-top rectangular box to slice via Cura for printing. Normally I would set up a solid box of the size I want in the modeler, and then subtract a slightly smaller box to create the final result.

- Is it possible to get the same results with Cura by instead only modeling the simpler solid box if set my wall lines and thickness for the base and sides, set the infill to 0 %, and then set the *Top Layers* to 0 and/or *Top Thickness* to 0 mm?
- How might that change the resulting print?
- How will that impact the total height of the print?

Comment: Why not just try it yourself?

Comment: Because even simple prints can take an hour of machine time. This was answered much faster, took no machine time, and I didn't have to wait 6 hours for my current print to finish to even start.

Comment: You don't need to print it to see the resulting path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that will work in Ultimaker Cura exactly as you say.

So if you have a solid model of a cube, you select wall thickness, bottom thickness, 0 % infill, and no top layers or top layer size of 0 mm. You will then end up with a box without a top layer, but with walls reaching up to the height of your model.

Comment: Can you do this to remove the bottom of a particular object as well?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes

Comment: Yes, you can even print no solid top, bottom, or side, and only print your infill shape/density if you like. I used to use this to make scaffolds.